# Is it possible to run HP DL580 G5 on just 2 processors and 2PSUs?

Tags: hp, central-processing-unit, electrical-power

So I just acquired a HP DL580 G5 server with the following config :

---

4X 6 core Xeon 7450 2.4GHz processors

128 GB RAM

6 X 72GB SAS drives 15K

---

I noticed that it requires at least 3 power inputs to function.
For right now I don't need the complete amount of the server's computing power and would like to minimize the power input it needs.

- Can I remove 2 processors along with the PPMs to reduce the power
  consumption and would it still work?
- Is there anything else that I can remove for it to function properly on at
  most 2 power units?

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You may have received a discount price on that used, because it is from 5 server models and about 10 years ago. The previous owner likely thought keeping it not worth the power consumption and heat generation. Consider instead getting 1 or 2 processors of something newer. A higher capital expense, but much better performance per Watt.

Comment: Yes I realize that. For now my Computing needs are not as high. I did start the server up on just two input powers and it didn't balk at me so for now i am content with the results. Thank you for the advice though. I do think I should resell it and buy something a little more cost effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That model can run with either 2 or 4 CPUs, not 1 or 3 - obviously you'll want to move the memory from CPU's 3 and 4 onto CPU's 1 and 2 but yes this should work just fine.

Comment: I have removed the Processors 3 and 4 along with their respective PPMs ! I'll let you know if it powers up tomorrow morning. I am not sure of the processors have a dedicated RAM per processor . Is there a document i can refer to for this ? (Researched but didn't find anything.)

Comment: Update : Started 2 processors on 2 power input. One necessary one redundant. So far so good. :thumbsup: